# VB.NET - What is the proper way to commit a subset of a byte buffer to file?

Tags: vb.net, io, buffer

I am concerned that this code is copying bytes into a temporary buffer before writing directly to file.

I feel like there should be some method of copying bytes directly from the tail end of the main buffer directly to file.

```
'this code copies all bytes starting at integer index from the main buffer into a new file: ga.exe

'declare temporary buffer
Dim EXEBytes(bytes.Count - index) As Byte

'copy subset of bytes over, starting at index 
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, index, EXEBytes, 0, bytes.Count - index)

'write bytes from temporary array into file
File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("/BIN/ga.exe"), EXEBytes)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better off using a stream, I believe:

```
Public Sub WriteFile(bytes As Byte(), index As Integer)
    Using oNewStream As IO.FileStream = IO.File.Open(Server.MapPath("/BIN/ga.exe"), IO.FileMode.Create)
        If oNewStream IsNot Nothing Then
            oNewStream.Write(bytes, index, bytes.Count - index)
            oNewStream.Close()
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```